# Jenkins slave configuration issue

Tags: jenkins

Have been trying for hours for setting up master-slave configuration in jenkins and getting this error when triggering the jnlp file from slave machine: "SEVERE: The server rejected the connection: None of the protocols were accepted
java.lang.Exception: The server rejected the connection: None of the protocols were accepted".. Everything seems set correctly from my end - Java 1.8.181 in both master and slave machines, jenkins 2.147 in both machines.

Here is the entire log: https://gist.github.com/anuraagkb/13f4f226a411fe02596af66be877257d

Comment: Can you post the command being used by slave to connect to the master ?

Comment: Check if your slave name is correct in your command

Comment: `The server rejected the connection: None of the protocols were accepted"..`, network issue, eg. visibility to the machines, or required ports are not open on the slave machine's firewall, something like this

Answer (score 0):

My bad..for the Jenkins URL under Manage Jenkins-> Configure System I had entered localhost instead of the server IP which caused the issue.